# How to check the data time is exist in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

There is a timetable system,

each timeslot is only exist one booking,

and I save data like this:

```
start_time datetime
duration int
```

That means, if booking from `2015-12-20 21:00:00 to 2015-12-20 23:00:00`
will be

```
start_time 2015-12-20 21:00:00
duration 3
```

Now , I would like to check whether the insert data are:

**1) time range overlap with exist record?**

**2) is exceed 24 hour? eg. booking from 22:00 but duration is 5 hour**

I attempt the condition like , but can't check with 24 hour

```
$start_time = new DateTime($_POST['start_time']);
$end_time = new DateTime($booking_time);
$end_time =  $end_time->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $_POST['duration']. 'H'));

$_POST['start_time'] >= start_time AND  end_time <= start_time
```

how to fix that?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second condition, are you trying to check if a booking will end in the same day as it will start?

If that's the case, the following select will return the bookings that matches this condition:

`SELECT start_time, duration FROM bookings WHERE DATE(start_time) <> DATE(TIMESTAMPADD(HOUR, duration, start_time));`